# VECM in cointegration analysis: How to chose the form of the deterministic terms from dataplots

Tags: time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression, cointegration

Please have a look at the plot of 5 different time series $Y_t=(y_{1,t},y_{2,t},y_{3,t},y_{4,t},y_{5,t})$. I want to use R's `urca` package to perform cointegration analysis on $Y_t$ using the VECM (*vector error corrected model*):
$$
\Delta Y_t = \Pi Y_{t-1} + \sum_{i=1}^k\Gamma_i\Delta Y_{t-i}+\Phi D_t +\epsilon_t
$$

- **How should I determine the *form* of the VECM regarding the deterministic term?**
- **Can I by "eyeball" method make a *reasonable* decision?**

The 3 most common ways are implemented in `urca`as: `trend = none,const drift`.

I am using these books:

- *Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R* by Pfaff
- *New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis* by Lütkepohl

Neither of these books say anything about this topic but in there examples (I think) they use the "eyeball" method[image]